# Remove react completely from iOS project

Tags: ios, react-native

I created an iOS project using react-native. I used react-native as well as swift in it. Now, I want to remove all the dependencies related to react-native, i.e., I want to make my app swift only.

I'm not able to find any documentation on react-native's developer portal (or anywhere else) related to this.

What steps should I follow to remove react-native completely?

Comment: Might be easier just to start a new Swift project in Xcode and copy your Swift files across.